does compactness and continuity ensure convexity
Give an example of a compact set D belongs to R^n and a continuous function f: D → R such that f(D) consists of precisely k points where k >= 2. Is this possible if D is also convex? Why or why not?
The thing is that for a disk like function where there is hole in the middle if we take linear combination for k=2 case only it will lie outside the domain even though the set is compact. Not convex. My problem is how to prove this.

This is more a matter of being connected than convex but convexity implies connectedness

A cheeky answer to the question as written would be to set $k = \omega_1$, but that's probably not the intended interpretation.

@julio_es_sui_glace can you explain me in simpler terms? I don't have a good exposition towards topology to understand what you mean. I have also checked the original question but still cannot understand anything.
